# How to correctly reset the underlying data of a UITableView?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a UITableView on one screen where the underlying datasource may change in structure - not just the individual cells.

If I jsut do that on the same UITableView and then call reload I get an error that the structure of the table has changed (like different number of rows, sections etc)

This is the error I get:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid
>   number of sections.  The number of sections contained in the table
>   view after the update (1) must be equal to the number of sections
>   contained in the table view before the update (21), plus or minus the
>   number of sections inserted or deleted (0 inserted, 0 deleted).'

Do I really have to change my table by deleting all sections and then adding the new ones?

So basically my question is how to do this correctly.
I could just create  a new UITableView programmatically, use the rect, bkgnd color, delegate and datasource from the initial table - but all the constraints I set in IB are lost for the new table.

How can I take all these constraints from the old table and give them to the new one?

> Even if I just set a new datasource I get the above error. Only if I
>   create a new UITableView with a new datasource I do not get the above
>   error.

Or is there another way to reset a UITableView with totally different underlying data while keeping all its UI attributes and constraints untouched?

Comment: What do you mean "totally different underlying data"? A UITableView should be able to change the number of rows and sections based on info from the datasource.

Comment: Are you actually calling `reloadData` or one of the other `reload...` methods?

Comment: Did you call `insertSections:withRowAnimation:`?

Comment: no I don't, I like to replace the complete underlying data, not just one row or section - or as written above - is this not possible and I have to use the delete and insert methods?

Comment: No you don't have to use insert/delete methods. rmaddy is correct. You should just update your data and call `reloadData'. I asked because the log suggests that you called the insert/delete sections methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is assign new data to whatever variables the various data source methods reference and call `reloadData` on the table view.

In other words, at the time you call `reloadData`, the calls to `numberOfSections`, `numberOfRowsInSection`, and `cellForRowAtIndexPath` *etc.* must all be referencing the same updated data.

Comment: that's basically what I do when assigning a new datasource, since all the references in the UITableView will now go to the new datasource - but I keep getting the above error again

Comment: Make sure you simply call `reloadData` and none of the other `reload...` related methods.

Comment: that did the trick - I had a begin and end update around my reload - deleting these 2 lines was the solution - thanks a lot!